# Wiring MVC4 to the latest JQuery, JQueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am positive I have the references correct as seen here:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
```

But my app still is not enabling this jQuery functionality:

```
<script>
$(function () {
$("#selectable").selectable();
});
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Thank you for your responses.  I tried updating the paths to the jquery libraries as the other posts suggested, but that had no effect.  I resolved this by commenting out the 2nd and 4th lines.  Here is the final code that worked.

```
<script>
//$(function () {
    $("#selectable").selectable();
//});
</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting some js error?

Comment: No, I never got an error.  The selectable feature just never worked.  I commented out the 2nd and 4th line and that did the trick.  That seems odd.  Maybe this is an MVC adaptation to not mark it as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your responses. I tried updating the paths to the jquery libraries as the other posts suggested, but that had no effect. I resolved this by commenting out the 2nd and 4th lines. Here is the final code that worked.

```
<script>
//$(function () {
$("#selectable").selectable();
//});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.js"></script>
```

The added forward slash enforces a relative url starting at the root of the website. Consider that your view must be in a folder like Home for example, so the url that your webpage is looking for for jquery is http://mywebsite.com/Home/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js which is not correct. The beginning forward slash enforces the relative url start at the root directory so the url will be http://mywebsite.com/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that the path is always correct use the UrlHelper method called Content.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js")"></script>
```

This will make the path work even in situations where you are not working in the root of the webserver. It will relate to the IIS application path.